# How to generate ETD(Electronic Trade Document) in magento with FedEx API?

Tags: magento-1.7, fedex

I can generate FedEx shipping label by FedEx Web-service in magento. That I have done by doing magento deafult FedEx shipping method configuration.There is no problem to do that But I can't generate ETD(Electronic Trade Document).I have attached two images which are some parts of my shipping label.In first One that I have generated through magento API.
Below quote describes what is ETD that I have derived from FedEx site.

> With Electronic Trade Documents shipping solution, you can submit your
>   customs documents electronically, so you don’t have to print multiple
>   copies and attach them to your packages. When you ship using FedEx
>   ETD, you’ll gain operational efficiencies, save time and money and
>   enjoy peace of mind.

[image]

In second one that I have generated through FedEx side for showing how actually the label should be.If this red circled label will appear then I can get a new pdf called Invoice pdf. I want that also.In magento admin I can get only to generate shipping label but not to generate invoice pdf which is meant for ETD.Can Any one please help me on that ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution after contacting to the FedEx support team for generating ETD.I just override the **Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex** model to my custom module **LR_Additional_Model_Usa_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex** by

```
 <usa>
     <rewrite>
           <shipping_carrier_fedex>LR_Additional_Model_Usa_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex</shipping_carrier_fedex>
     </rewrite>
 </usa>
```

then edited the function **_formShipmentRequest** and added some xml elements which are meant for ETD element after the line - 1406. by following codes:

```
   $europianUnionCountryCodes = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/country/eu_countries');
   $euCountryCode = array();
   if($europianUnionCountryCodes){
       $euCountryCode = explode(',',$europianUnionCountryCodes);
   }

    if (($request->getShipperAddressCountryCode() != $request->getRecipientAddressCountryCode()) &&
    (!in_array($request->getRecipientAddressCountryCode(),$euCountryCode) && !in_array($request->getShipperAddressCountryCode(),$euCountryCode))) {
    /*Etd element section starts here */
        $requestClient['RequestedShipment']['SpecialServicesRequested'] = array(
    'SpecialServiceTypes' => 'ELECTRONIC_TRADE_DOCUMENTS',
    'EtdDetail' => array(
        'RequestedDocumentCopies' => 'COMMERCIAL_INVOICE'
    )
    );
    $requestClient['RequestedShipment']['ShippingDocumentSpecification'] = array(
    'ShippingDocumentTypes' => 'COMMERCIAL_INVOICE',
    'CommercialInvoiceDetail' => array(
        'Format' => array(
        'ImageType' => 'PDF',
        'StockType' => 'PAPER_LETTER',
        )
    )
    );
    $requestClient['RequestedShipment']['EdtRequestType'] = 'ALL';
    /*Etd element section ends here */
        $requestClient['RequestedShipment']['CustomsClearanceDetail'] =
            array(
                'CustomsValue' =>
                array(
                    'Currency' => $order->getOrderCurrencyCode(),
                    'Amount' => $customsValue,
                ),
                'DutiesPayment' => array(
                    'PaymentType' => $paymentType,
                    'Payor' => array(
                        'AccountNumber' => $this->getConfigData('account'),
                        'CountryCode'   => Mage::getStoreConfig(
                            Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping::XML_PATH_STORE_COUNTRY_ID,
                            $request->getStoreId()
                        )
                    )
                ),
                'Commodities' => array(
                    'Weight' => array(
                        'Units' => $weightUnits,
                        'Value' =>  $request->getPackageWeight()
                    ),
                    'NumberOfPieces' => 1,
                    'CountryOfManufacture' => implode(',', array_unique($countriesOfManufacture)),
                    'Description' => implode(', ', $itemsDesc),
                    'Quantity' => ceil($itemsQty),
                    'QuantityUnits' => 'pcs',
                    'UnitPrice' => array(
                        'Currency' => $request->getBaseCurrencyCode(),
                        'Amount' =>  $unitPrice
                    ),
                    'CustomsValue' => array(
                        'Currency' => $request->getBaseCurrencyCode(),
                        'Amount' =>  $customsValue
                    ),
                )
            );
    }
```

The solution I have made in Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 only I am not sure for other versions of magento. Also magento doesn't have functionality to accept ETD label. It only accept Shipping label and save that shipping label into **sales_flat_shipment** in column **shipping_label** . So for invoice label I have managed in another way like fetch that label from the response comes from FedEx Api and save with my custom table as it is vast answer so I am not explaining everything. I am just explaining only possibilities that I have done.

Magento generally fetch the label by:

```
 $shippingLabelContent = $response->CompletedShipmentDetail->CompletedPackageDetails->Label->Parts->Image;
```

In same way I have fetched the invoice label by:

```
 $lr_invoice_label_content = $response->CompletedShipmentDetail->ShipmentDocuments->Parts->Image;
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. it helps me a lot. using you solution i am able to submit the ETD detail. but can you please tell me how can i fetch and store the commercial invoice.

Comment: @ajay you can do one thing just go to https://www.fedex.com/en-us/developer.html and search any documents available to that API. You will be getting and every details over there whatever service they are providing.